# Persisting MySQL data in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I am new to Docker. I have successfully created a Docker *image* with the following Dockerfile:

```
From alpine:3.4
MAINTAINER SomeName - domain.tld

# Timezone
ENV TIMEZONE Asia/Kolkata

# RUN sed -i 's#dl-cdn\.alpinelinux\.org#mirrors\.aliyun\.com#' /etc/apk/repositories

# install mysql, apache and php and php extensions, tzdata, wget
RUN echo "@community http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    apk add --update \
    mysql mysql-client \
    apache2 \
    curl wget \
    tzdata \
    php5-apache2 \
    php5-cli \
    php5-phar \
    php5-zlib \
    php5-zip \
    php5-bz2 \
    php5-ctype \
    php5-mysqli \
    php5-mysql \
    php5-pdo_mysql \
    php5-opcache \
    php5-pdo \
    php5-json \
    php5-curl \
    php5-gd \
    php5-gmp \
    php5-mcrypt \
    php5-openssl \
    php5-dom \
    php5-xml \
    php5-iconv \
    php5-xdebug@community

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
    php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer

# configure timezone, mysql, apache
RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TIMEZONE} /etc/localtime && \
    echo "${TIMEZONE}" > /etc/timezone && \
    mkdir -p /run/mysqld && chown -R mysql:mysql /run/mysqld /var/lib/mysql && \
    mysql_install_db --user=mysql --verbose=1 --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --rpm > /dev/null && \
    mkdir -p /run/apache2 && chown -R apache:apache /run/apache2 && chown -R apache:apache /var/www/localhost/htdocs/ && \
    sed -i 's#AllowOverride none#AllowOverride All#' /etc/apache2/httpd.conf && \
    sed -i 's#ServerName www.example.com:80#\nServerName localhost:80#' /etc/apache2/httpd.conf && \
    sed -i '/skip-external-locking/a log_error = \/var\/lib\/mysql\/error.log' /etc/mysql/my.cnf && \
    sed -i '/skip-external-locking/a general_log = ON' /etc/mysql/my.cnf && \
    sed -i '/skip-external-locking/a general_log_file = \/var\/lib\/mysql\/query.log' /etc/mysql/my.cnf

# Configure xdebug
RUN echo "zend_extension=xdebug.so" > /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini && \ 
    echo -e "\n[XDEBUG]"  >> /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini && \ 
    echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini && \  
    echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1" >> /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini && \ 
    echo "xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM" >> /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini && \ 
    echo "xdebug.remote_log=\"/tmp/xdebug.log\"" >> /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini

#start apache
RUN echo "#!/bin/sh" > /start.sh && \
    echo "httpd" >> /start.sh && \
    echo "nohup mysqld --skip-grant-tables --bind-address 0.0.0.0 --user mysql > /dev/null 2>&1 &" >> /start.sh && \
    echo "sleep 3 && mysql -uroot -e \"create database db;\"" >> /start.sh && \
    echo "tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log" >> /start.sh && \
    chmod u+x /start.sh

WORKDIR /var/www/localhost/htdocs/

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 3306

#VOLUME ["/var/www/localhost/htdocs","/var/lib/mysql","/etc/mysql/"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```

Ideally I want the docker image to contain Apache, PHP and MySQL -- all in one image. I want the image to be as portable as possible. So that every time I need to start a new project, I can just create a new container and mount volumes and go ahead and code.

When I start a new container, I get everything as expected. But the mysql data cannot be mounted. I think it is because the mounting is one-way (or is it?) If I add `-v /project_dir/data:/var/lib/mysql` while starting a new container, mysql doesn't start up because the `project_dir/data` is empty. My questions are:

1. How to mount data from my `project_dir` to `/var/lib/mysql` *inside* the container?
2. How can I set different mysql passwords to different containers?

**Edit:** If I don't mount my local volume (i.e. `project_dir/data`) and start the container, get a shell tty, I see that `/var/lib/mysql` has several files, which I assume are needed to run mysql and its initial databases. But if I mount my local volume and `ls` inside `/var/lib/mysql` (inside the container), it is empty. That is why MySQL is not starting up and I cannot persist data from *outside* the container. My question is: how I can get it running and persist data from local directory.

Comment: Image is supposed to be independent on your local environment. You have to use VOLUME to mark directory which will be mounted from outside. And when you run image in docker you connect it to your local environment using `-v` parameters.This way it works even on Kubernetes.

Comment: Don't use Docker for this use case. Docker is an application container technology. You are building a OS container / Golden image. Use a VM or if you insist on using containers just to be cool, use the OS container (e.g. OpenVZ). You will run in lots of problems with your current aproach.

Answer (score 4):

**The problem**:

What's going on here is that you create an empty database while the Docker image is being built:

```
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --verbose=1 --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --rpm > /dev/null && \
```

But when you create a container from this image, you mount a volume on the `/var/lib/mysql` folder. This hides your containers data, to expose your host's folder. Thus, you're seeing an empty folder.

**The solution**:

If you take a look at https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/, you'll see that this problem is addressed by creating the database when the container actually starts, not when the image is created. This answers both your questions:

1. If you start your container with your mounted volume, then the database init will be executed afterwards, and your data will actually be written in your host's FS
2. You have to pass those information as env variables

In other words, init your DB with a script in an `ENTRYPOINT`, rather than directly in the image.

**Warnings**:

Some warnings, though. The way you did your image is not really recommended, because Docker's philosophy is "one process per container". The difficulty you have here is that you'll have to start multiple services on the same container (apache, Mysql, etc.), so you may have to do things on both in your entrypoint, which is confusing. Also, is one service fails, your container will still be up, but not working as expected.

I then would suggest to split what you did in as 1 image per process, then either start them all with raw Docker, or user something like `docker-compose`.

Also, this will benefit you in the way that you'll be able to use already existing and highly configurable images, from the Docker Hub : https://hub.docker.com. Less job for you and less error prone.

Comment: Thank you. Makes a lot of sense. However, I am really new to Docker. Could you please explain a bit more about how to add a script in `ENTRYPOINT`? Isn't `ENTRYPOINT` used inside Dockerfile? If so, what is the difference between _running the script when the image is built_ and _running the script when container starts_? Isn't Dockerfile used only for building the image?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/tree/10eb5eab8d3d793c49a701ed7a42e1e5d1c9bb59/8.0. This is how the MySQL image is done. Once again, I encourage you to use it (choose the mysql version you need, though). Now to answer your questions: `ENTRYPOINT` is a command that is to be executed when the container starts. In order to do so, you have to define it in the Dockerfile. So yes, the Dockerfile is use to build the image, but also given instructions on what to do when you create a container out of it. For instance, configure and start a process.

Answer (score -1):

When you have a database in a docker container, using a volume is the only way to go. Maybe we should state that "database inside your container" means not using a volume and having the data in the standard 10GB (or bigger if the default size has been modified) and database in a volume means `docker run -v myvolume...`

the doc docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes is a must-see

I completely agree with Alexandre's answer, but I think it is wrong to put your database inside your container, also for another reason. By default, the size of an image (so a container when you run it) is 10 GB. This should be quite comfortable for some executables, libraries and configuration files. You can modify this default, and put a larger value when creating your image. But what happens when you hit this new limit ? Suppose you think the size your database will be 100 GB, and in fact, you put more data than planned, and you eventually need 5 or 20 times more? A volume can be on a SAN and extended if needed.

Comment: What do you mean: "put your database inside your container" ? You mean NOT using a volume ?

Comment: No, I mean using volume is the only way for storing a database

Comment: Ok, then my answer may not be clear enough, because this is what I advise as well :). Do you see how I could improve it ?

Comment: @user2915097 -- Either move that comment into your Answer, or delete your answer as being confusing.